# Check if class is a valid value for KParameter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Given the following example code

```
fun function(text: CharSequence) {
    println(text)
}

val textParam = ::function.parameters[0]
val stringClass = String::class
```

How can I check if `textParam` accepts `stringClass` as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following with `KClass`:

```
val paramClass = ::function.parameters[0].type.jvmErasure

println(stringClass.isSubclassOf(paramClass))
```

Alternatively, another solution with checking `KType`:

```
val paramType = ::function.parameters[0].type

println(stringClass.starProjectedType == paramType ||  // type is String
        stringClass.allSupertypes.contains(paramType)) // type is a supertype of String
```